# replace pandas dataframe with a unique id

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I got a dataframe with millions of entries, with one of the columns 'TYPE' (string).  There is a total of 400 values for this specific column and I want to replace the values with integer id starting from 1 to 400. I also want to export this dictionary 'TYPE' => id for future reference. I tried with to_dict but it did not help.  Anyway  can do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** you can use [pd.factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.factorize(df['str_col'])[0]+1
```

**Option 2:** using category dtype:

```
df['new'] = df['str_col'].astype('category').cat.codes+1
```

or even better just convert it to categorical dtype:

```
df['str_col'] = df['str_col'].astype('category')
```

and when you need to use numbers instead just use category codes:

```
df['str_col'].cat.codes
```

thanks to [@jezrael for extending the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248490/replace-pandas-dataframe-with-a-unique-id/48248504?noredirect=1#comment83479583_48248504) - for creating a dictionary:

```
cats = df['str_col'].cat.categories
d = dict(zip(cats, range(1, len(cats) + 1)))
```

PS category dtype is very memory-efficient too

Comment: And for dictionary `cats = df['str_col'].cat.categories
d = dict(zip(cats, range(1, len(cats) + 1)))`